# Does anyone know why python dateutil parser is telling me it contains invalid syntax? It worked last night, will not work anymore

Tags: python, parsing, python-dateutil

```
 from dateutil import parser as _date_parser
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\dateutil\parser.py", line 158
    l.append("%s=%s" % (attr, `value`))
                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

My code was no different last night when I ran it. Had no problems then, but now I'm getting this SyntaxError from the dateutil parser. Here's the code from the parser itself:

```
def _repr(self, classname):
    l = []
    for attr in self.__slots__:
    value = getattr(self, attr)
    if value is not None:
        l.append("%s=%s" % (attr, `value`))
    return "%s(%s)" % (classname, ", ".join(l))
```

Comment: `l.append("%s=%s" % (attr, value))` chnage to this.

Answer (score 4):

Last night you used Python 2. Today you used Python 3.

In Python 2 backticks were used as a shortcut to `repr`. In Python 3 this alias is not used anymore and using it raises a syntax error.

Change

```
l.append("%s=%s" % (attr, `value`))
```

to either `l.append("%s=%s" % (attr, value))` or `l.append("%s=%s" % (attr, repr(value)))`

**EDIT** I just noticed that this code is in `dateutil` itself. It seems like you somehow managed to install the Python 2 version to the Python 3 path.

Comment: "The Python 2 version" would have to be a super old version of dateutil, which has been polyglot for *years*.